# Make the tags closed in pairs with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm

I use the code live template, the react-native tag auto close with one tag, for example is `<View/>`, but usually using `<View></View>`.

Can I set the WebStorm to this style?

Comment: not sure I follow you... Would you like WebStorm to generate self-closing tags (`<View/>`) rather than `<View></View>` in JSX? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25937 is fixed in 2017.1.2

Comment: I am learning react jsx .I want webstorm  to generate  tags (<View></View>,not singe<View>)

Comment: hmm.. doesn't it? Please can you elaborate on your issue? What did you do exactly?

Comment: Same issue here. When I type `<V` and use WebStorm auto-completion, it generates `<View/>` instead of `<View></View>`. Same for all other React Native elements I tried, like `Text`, `Card`... But most of the time I would expect the expanded element.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm for React development and this is driving me crazy (e.g. react-bootstrap column always self closes to <Col />...). Has anyone found a way to configure whether a certain tag should self-close or create a pair of tags?

Answer (score 7):

## Solution

One solution to this problem is the creation of a `snippet` with WebStorm.

### What is a `snippet` in WebStorm?

The `snippets` are **code portions** that **we usually reuse in our code work; that is, that portion of code that contains a pattern to be repeated at any time**.

*For example, the following is a snippet :*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="es">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

### How to implement it?

#### Creation

- Open our WebStorm IDE

  [image: ![A1124](A112_images/A1124.png)]
- Go to `File> Settings` or   <kbd>CTRL+ ALT + S</kbd> .
- Search `Editor` `(1)` → `Live Templates` `(2)`. You can also use `seeker` (3)
- You will find a select `(4)` to choose which key will expand the snippet.

  - By default it is tab (it is the most comfortable).
- Below, `(5)` you will see all existing groups and lives templates (*Webstorm already has several factory*).
- In the part on the right (6) you will see buttons for `add` (+),`delete` (-), `duplicate` or`restore` live templates.

  *Note: You can add groups or live templates. It is advisable to add a group first to organize better.*

#### Implementation

Once you have created your group (in my case EDgrid), we will create our first Live template by pressing the + symbol (indicated in the previous step).

The first thing we will do is the creation of a new `Template Group`, in our case we will ponder`React`, selected on the group `React`:

[image: ![A112](A112_images/A112.png)]

We press `Ok`.

The next step will be the creation of a new `Live Template`:

[image: ![A1121](A112_images/A1121.png)]

- In the field `Abbreviation` we enter the name to get the name when we want to create the custom snippet:
- In the `Description` field, insert a personalized description or leave it empty.
- In the `Template Text` field we will introduce

  ```
  <View>$END$</View>
  ```

Next we will define the content to apply in `Define`:

[image: ![A1123](A112_images/A1123.png)]

*We choose `Javascript`*.

#### Note

*Remember that this can change how your snippet acts in terms of formatting style*.

[image: ![A1122](A112_images/A1122.png)]

---

## Test

[image: ![GIF](A112_images/gif.gif)]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ.

I have update to new version (2018) and resolve it.